# Check two variables signum with condition

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-logic

Given 2 integers and condition `negative`:

- return `true` if one is below zero and one is above zero and `negative` is `false`.
- return `true` if both are below zero and `negative` is `true`.
- return `false` otherwise.

Tests:

```
posNeg(1, -1, false) expected: true
posNeg(-1, 1, false) expected: true
posNeg(-4, -5, true) expected: true
posNeg(-4, 5, true)  expected: false
```

My solution to the problem is :

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
  return ((((a>0) && (b<0)) || ((a<0) && (b>0))) || (((a<0) && (b<0)) &&(negative))); 
}
```

But It is wrong for the case

```
posNeg(-4, 5, true) expected: false | actual: true
```

I think my solution is right after checking again several times.

Kindly let me know where I am wrong. Why this solution is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three cases in an or relation to each other. Since one of the cases is "a is negative and b is positive", it will return true.

You need to make sure the first two cases only return true if negative is false.

For example instead of

```
((a>0) && (b<0))
```

write

```
(a > 0 && b < 0 && !negative)
```

Answer (score 1):

`(a<0) && (b>0)` is `true` for (-4, 5).

`(X || true) || Y = true`

Refactor condition like this:

```
return negative && a < 0 && b < 0
       || !negative && (a < 0 && b > 0 || a > 0 && b < 0);
```

or

```
if (negative) return a < 0 && b < 0;
else return a < 0 && b > 0 || a > 0 && b < 0;
```

or

```
return negative 
    ? a < 0 && b < 0
    : a < 0 && b > 0 || a > 0 && b < 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey. That was helpful.

Comment: Or: Use an actual `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

First you check whether

```
(a>0) && (b<0) || (a<0) && (b>0)
```

without looking if `negative` is `true` or `false`. Conditions are checked from left to right.

This makes both

```
posNeg(-4, 5, true)
posNeg(-4, 5, false)
```

evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is short solution.

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
    return negative == a > 0 == b > 0;
}
```